# Annual compounding and how it changes during the year

Tags: analysis, logarithms, exponential-function

I was reading from a book that if we compound annually at $40\%$ the rate of growth at any instant, such as $P$ in the following graphs (AL represents $1$ year) will be $40\%$ of the value at the beginning of the year. If we compound semi-annually the rate will be $40\%$ of the value at the beginning of the half-year in which $P$ lies etc
[image]

At this point I am confused because my understanding of annual compounding is that there is $1$ change in the original amount at the end of the year i.e. the graph (assuming $\$100$ at the start) should be:
[image]

I.e. no change until $L$ and a sudden jump in the graph at $L$

What am I misunderstanding here? I think it will be $\$140$ only at $L$ so $P$ should be $40\%$ of the beginning value only at $M$ and not earlier

Comment: Technically, the compounding interval and the payment interval need not be the same.

Comment: @GEdgar: The book I am reading is about mathematical analysis and not economics in case it matters. So I would assume the distinction you are making is when we are talking about economics?

Comment: @GEdgar: even so how would they be $40\%$ from the start at any instant? This is confusing to me. The only value $40\%$ of the start is $140$ and that is at the end of the interval